# How to track function calls in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I would like a way to track all function calls that have operated on a specific workspace variable -- for instance, a sound waveform that will be transformed by various signal processing functions.

One cumbersome and fragile way is to do this:

```
>> cfg = [];
>> curr_call = 'data_out = my_function(cfg,data_in);';
>> eval(curr_call);
>> data_out.cfg.history = cat(1,data_out.cfg.history,{curr_call});
```

What would be much better is the following:

```
>> cfg = [];
>> data_out = my_function(cfg,data_in);
>> data_out.cfg.history

  'data_out = my_function(cfg,data_in);'
```

**EDIT** for clarification: In other words, this variable has a field, `cfg.history`, that keeps track of all history-enabled functions that have operated on it (ideally with arguments). The history field should be updated regardless of where function calls originate: my example above is from the command line, but calls made from cell mode or within a script should also be appended to the history. Obviously, I can edit `my_function()` in the above example so that it can modify the history field.

**NOTE** in response to discussion below: the motivation for doing this is to have the  history "attached" to the data in question, rather than say, in a separate log file which would then need to be packaged with the data somehow.

Can this be done?

Comment: how about using the Profiler?

Comment: interesting! the Profiler's FunctionHistory contains (among many other things) the name of the last function called. This does not give access to the arguments used to make the call, though -- or does it?

Comment: @MattMizumi: The profiler summarizes over all calls, there is no usefull way to summarize many sets of parameters so the information is not listed.

Comment: I have to ask what is it you are trying to do here? Why not just use logging/tracing to keep track of such information? Something like this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37701-log4m-a-powerful-and-simple-logger-for-matlab

Comment: sure, but it would be convenient if the provenance information is inseparable from the data of interest. that way, when processed data is passed around (between different analysis pipeline stages, or between people) the history of a piece of processed data can always be traced.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the full Session history using this code:

```
import com.mathworks.mlservices.MLCommandHistoryServices
history=MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory;
```

To achive what you want, use this code:

```
import com.mathworks.mlservices.MLCommandHistoryServices;
startcounter=numel(MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory);
disp('mydummycommand');
disp('anotherdummycommand');
history=MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory;
commands=cell(history(startcounter-2:end-1));
```

Be aware that these functions are undocumented. It uses the command history which is typically located at the bottom right in your matlab.

Comment: Clever! This would work for function calls issued from the command line, but not for cell mode or from inside scripts and functions. Ideally there would be a more general solution.

Comment: @MattMizumi: Please update your question and make clear what you want. Do you want a full recursive list of all commands executed? That will rapidly become a huge structure.

Comment: @MattMizumi: Okay a explicit whitelist of functions you want to log makes it clear. I don't have a solution for this.

Comment: updated. I only care about function calls (all of which functions I can edit) that operate on the variable of interest. So in each of those functions, I can add whatever code is needed to update the history field of the variable.